# Converting from VB6 to C# over MSCOMM to serialport

Tags: c#, vb6

I am trying to send some data to a LED display that works over serial port. This code does the job over VB6 but i needed to convert it to C#. Sadly it does not work. Any ideas?

**VB6 (Example)**

```
MSComm1.CommPort = 1

MSComm1.Settings = "9600,N,8,1"

MSComm1.PortOpen = True

MSComm1.Output = Chr(170)

MSComm1.Output = Chr(2)
```

**C# (Example)**

```
var serialPort1 = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

serialPort1.Open();

serialPort1.Write(((char)170).ToString());

serialPort1.Write(((char)2).ToString());

serialPort1.Close();
```

I think the problem is about serialPort1.Write function but i could not figure it out. Can you help please?

Comment: Are you getting an error or is the LCD just not responding?

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is messing with the Handshake property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.handshake.aspx

Comment: Have you tries writing a bytearray instead of a string. The basestream of a serialport has some encoding that might be in the way. Something like this: `sp.Write(new byte [] { 170 }, 0, 1);`

Comment: Yes, i tried it too and still not working. I am also trying MSComm class in C# atm since i have not got any specific result from SerialPort class...

Comment: Do you have a technical reference of the lcd screen? Something where the protocol is described in?

Comment: Yeah i have a manual but it is VB code based. I wanted to convert it to C#, was able to success about port connection but led screen does not recognize the commands that i send over c# via Write() function :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also figured out how to do it with serialPort class. The important deal is using designer to add serialPort1 definition instead of manual definition with "var serialPort1 = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);". My problem occured because of missing definitions i guess. Here is the sample :

```
Byte[] _bytesToSend = new Byte[7];
_bytesToSend[0] = 170;
_bytesToSend[1] = 2;
serialPort1.Open();
serialPort1.Write(_bytesToSend, 0, _bytesToSend.Length);
serialPort1.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

I just solved my problem with using MSComm class in C#. Ty everybody for all help :)

Comment: It's a shame you still have a dependency on COM components...  It seems like getting the newer .NET version of the SerialPort code should be doable.